# How can I maintain a list of constant masters and workers under conf/masters and conf/workers in a managed Scaling cluster?

Tags: amazon-emr, alluxio

I am using an AWS EMR cluster with  Alluxio installed n every node. I want to now deploy Alluxio in High Availability.
https://docs.alluxio.io/os/user/stable/en/deploy/Running-Alluxio-On-a-HA-Cluster.html#start-an-alluxio-cluster-with-ha
I am following the above documentation, and see that "On all the Alluxio master nodes, list all the worker hostnames in the `conf/workers` file, and list all the masters in the `conf/masters` file".

My concern is that since I have an AWS-managed scaling cluster the worker nodes keep added and removed based on cluster loads. How can I maintain a list of constant masters and workers under conf/masters and conf/workers in a managed Scaling cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this `conf/workers` and `conf/masters` conf file is only used for intiial setup through scripts. Once the cluster is running, you don’t need to update them any more.

E.g., in an say EMR cluster, you can add a new slave node as Alluxio worker and as long as you specify the correct Alluxio master address, this new Alluxio worker will be able to register itself and serve in the fleet like other workers,